# Laptop overheating

Tags: laptop, cpu, fan, temperature

Okay so, I have a acer nitro 5 (that's all I know) intel core i5 processor, and a nvidia gtx 1050.

Now, I have this laptop for 2 years now, and recently, yes only recently, I have noticed that the thing gets incredibly hot! If I hover my hand over the keyboard I can feel the hot air. Now I am not a laptop nerd but I am intelligent enough to realize that that isn't normal....
So I downloaded an application that, eh... "analyses" the temperature. When idle it's around 40-50+°c. When I play roblox, u proably know it literally potato computers can run it, it goes up to around 64°c.
So I was like:"that's already too hot..."
So I launched wolfquest, it's a fairly heavy game now, and umm... my CPU and GPU went up to 90°c. That's also where u can feel the heat if u hold ur hand above the keyboard.

Now the problem seems to be clear now.
But I need a solution one that shouldn't be to expensive.

I did notice that the fans are on the bottom of my laptop, so maybe I jsut need a stand, but I still feel like there's something else that needs improvement or fixing.

The fans are clean btw I checked that. And my laptop also returned from a repair recently. And it came back totally clean. So I doubt they left the fans dusty.

So anyway if u got solutions for me they are very appreciated :)

Comment: "recently, yes only recently" and "returned from a repair recently."  See where I'm going with this?

Comment: oh the heat discovery was some months before the repair, the repair of the SSD was 2 weeks ago...

Comment: So the fans are clean, but what about the heatsinks?  Ever taken the bottom of the laptop off ?  I thought the thermal paste advice below was a joke, but I seem to have been mistaken.  Have a look here: https://community.acer.com/en/discussion/545316/acer-nitro-5-overheating/p2

Answer (score -2):

I would recommend Arctic Silver 5 Thermal Paste. The thermal paste is easy to apply and it will fix your overheating issue. It fixed mine so hopefully, it will work for you too.

Comment: Do you think the laptop's design has changed in the years he owns it?